# Is it possible to use Nodejs in mobile application?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mobile

I already did some applications in computer using Nodejs and Mongodb. Is it possible for me to use this projects and run in mobile platforms. Or should I write all the project in Android starting from the scratch?

Comment: I found something; http://jxcore.com/home/ But don't know whether it's suitable for me.

Comment: Here is the JXcore in wikipedia page; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#JXcore

Answer (score 2):

This question is kind of vague. A mobile application would be written natively (iOS, Android, maybe Xamarin or Unity for cross-platform), or could be written as a web app (a HTML5 web page), and turned into a "mobile app" via PhoneGap, Cordova, Crosswalk or just opening a web browser.

As far as running nodejs and mongo natively on the device, you need to explain more. Those are server-side technologies and I'm not sure why you'd want them on a mobile device. So the answer is "no" without it just being some tech experiment.

Can mobile apps talk to and utilize your Node server application? Absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

Any apis specific to these platforms won't work within mobile application.
There is plugin on-boards very limited NodeJS apis by translating them to their native equivalents.
For Example : [NativeScript-Nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify)